# "A graphics problem has been detected"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

MacBookPro11,3
2.5 GHz i7
Intel Iris Pro and NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M (auto graphics switching on, it was on intel)
OSX 10.10.1

The system appeared to freeze. iStat Menu's clock stopped, the cursor wouldn't move, etc. I tried (physically) closing and reopening, but it didn't go to sleep and the apple logo light on the back stayed on. Option-command-power and option-control-power also didn't do anything. After force shutdown (long press of power button) and startup, it asked if I wanted to reopen Finder windows after force quitting it, "you shut down your computer because of a problem", and:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do3pw.png]

There's not much I was doing, there's not that much I have installed (relatively new computer). I'm guessing it was Focusrite's Saffire Mix Control. Or maybe Safari.

Here's some console:

```
12/9/14 20:17:21.209 apsd[52]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
12/9/14 20:17:21.216 apsd[52]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
12/9/14 20:17:21.222 apsd[52]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
12/9/14 20:17:21.223 xpcproxy[384]: CFPreferences could not connect to its daemon.
 Preferences using the connection 0x0 will be volatile and will not be persisted to disk.
12/9/14 20:17:21.224 xpcproxy[386]: CFPreferences could not connect to its daemon.
 Preferences using the connection 0x0 will be volatile and will not be persisted to disk.
12/9/14 20:17:21.227 apsd[52]: Attempt to set push wake topics without dark wake enabled: ()
12/9/14 20:17:21.276 askpermissiond[385]: objc[385]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
12/9/14 20:17:21.337 locationd[57]: Couldn't find a requirement string for masquerading client /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Parsec.framework
12/9/14 20:17:21.338 locationd[57]: could not get apple languages array, assuming english
12/9/14 20:17:21.368 mapspushd[397]: [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all accounts
12/9/14 20:17:21.368 mapspushd[397]: [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all enabled accounts
12/9/14 20:17:21.368 mapspushd[397]: [Warning] Services all disappeared, removing all dependent devices
12/9/14 20:17:21.422 askpermissiond[385]: StoreTransport: Resetting APS Connection using environment name production
12/9/14 20:17:21.535 storeaccountd[286]: AccountServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fc3b100a0e0> connection from pid 379 with interface <AccountServiceInterface: 0x7fc3b100a7e0> (PID 379)
12/9/14 20:17:21.551 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.637 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny file-read-metadata /Library
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
12/9/14 20:17:21.000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: appleeventsd(25) deny mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
```

What caused the crash?

Comment: Apple has a pretty good loging system. Open your Console and look at the time stamp just before it happened, then copy and paste here.

Comment: bjb568, I think that @Buscar웃 was asking for not just the time stamp but a few full lines around the time just before this error occurred. The stamp alone won't help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, my instructions were not clear. Select some 20 lines before and some 20 lines after the Tue Dec 9 20:17:17, then copy paste (the whole text). I know and do not worry, some people can actually read and understand that stuff :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 Oh, that, ok. Edited.

Comment: That was almost ok, but we are missing the Tue Dec 9 20:17:17 lines.

Comment: @Buscar웃 http://pastebin.com/N8Zd19jJ

Comment: ok, going there :)

Comment: you have lots of stuff going on, from 3d party apps! Disable them all and try again, I bet it does not happen in Safe mode.

Comment: Which year is this machine from and is it an retina MacBook?

Comment: @Dempa Mid 2014, retina.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known and serious issue with the retina MBP and Yosemite, particularly the 2012 retina but other retina owners are reporting this problem too. Far as I know it's limited to the 15 inch machines, at least from what I've been reading. Yosemite basically crashes on graphics switching. Check out the lengthy forum posts over on apple.com. Basically, all you can do for now is turn off graphics switching and prey they solve it in the next version. I posted a radar to them some weeks ago on the topic and engineering requested more information. So, they definitely know about it. Some people on Macrumours were posting that the latest beta solved the issue, but it's probably too soon to tell. The down side of turing off graphics switching is that it reduces battery life significantly, but at least you can still use your machine.

Comment: I tried turning of graphics switching, but it didn't help.

Comment: If it's not a retina machine then it's probably something else. Can you replicate the problem or is it just a one off thing? If it's repeatable then try safe booting. If it still does it under safe boot then it's probably hardware related. The tough thing is if it's intermittent. Hope it's not hardware man.

Comment: It's a "MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)". It comes up ones every few weeks, not seemingly triggered by anything. I reproduced it once on a 2009 mac pro on yosemite (with similar 3rd party apps as the MBP).

Comment: Definitely take it in. The forum post I've been looking through showed most users are able to work around this by turning off graphics switching. You might want to check out this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602046?tstart=0 . There are a bunch of suggestions to troubleshoot the issue. Start with PRAM and SMC. You can also run a hardware diagnostic on the machine which might report something. Remove anything that's altering the kernel, such as FLUX. Also, have a look through the logs.  /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports you're looking for a kernelXXXXX.panic file.

Comment: In the DiagnosticReports there were no .panic files, but I found something from that time that mentioned Chrome Pepper Flash Player.

Comment: Running hardware diagnostics reported nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should look for a .log file with panic in the name. If you are unable to find the correct panic.log file, the most recent panic information may still be in nvram.  Try entering "nvram -p" on the command line (using Terminal) to retrieve the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20101/discussion-between-bjb568-and-cocoanut).

Comment: This issue is NOT with just retina MBPs. Users with non-retina MBPs (including myself) have experienced this too, but the non-retina MBPs are much less common now so there are less reports.

Comment: @shrx thing is in some cases this can be an underlying hardware issue. In the case of 2012 retina machines the problem is widely reported unlike other models, so is most likely a driver issue. If you have this issue and you don't have a 15 inch retina 2012 then I would take the machine in esp if you have a warranty.  Good luck.

Comment: @cocoanut It's a driver issue. I have installed a different driver from Nvidia following the suggestion from apple discussions thread and haven't had any lockups since. I will test the computer for a few more days and then post the detailed instructions as an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed a GPU driver from NVidia and I haven't had any freezes for a month. I have then switched back to the native driver and I got a freeze in less than a day. So I am fairly confident that a different driver fixes the issue.
The driver installation procedure is not straightforward, but is well documented on [Daniel Kramnik's website](https://xellers.wordpress.com/articles/how-to-install-osx-drivers-on-unsupported-systems/).

- First, go to [NVidia drivers download page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and download a driver which works on OS X, for example [Quadro K5000 for Mac - Quadro ODE Graphics Driver](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/Mac/Quadro_Certified/343.02.02f01/WebDriver-343.02.02f01.pkg&lang=us&type=GeForce).
- Then, download "Auxilliary Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012" on the [Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/). You don't have to have a paid Apple developer program membership.
- Mount the downloaded Auxiliary Tools `.dmg` and drag `PackageMaker` to your `/Applications/` folder.
- Right click on the downloaded NVidia driver `.pkg` and select `Open With -> Flat Package Editor`.
- Drag the `Distribution` file out from the `Flat Package Editor` and place it in a folder, for example alongside the downloaded driver.
- Open the `Distribution` file in a text editor and remove the line

  `if (!validateHardware()) return false;`
- Save the edited file, delete the original `Distribution` file in the `Flat Package Editor` and replace it with the edited one.
- Save the modified driver `.pkg` and run it. You should be able to install the NVidia GPU driver.
- Restart your computer to start using the NVidia GPU driver.

Credit for the suggestion to try a different driver goes to [Shmup Fiend](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27468678#27468678) in the original apple discussions thread.
Credit for the driver installation procedure goes to Daniel Kramnik, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the Focusrite's Saffire Mix Control since that's a 3rd party app (I think).

Try going to `System Preferences > Energy Saver` and make sure all of the setting are to your liking.

If this problem persists, try turning off Automatic Graphic Switching in both the `Battery` and `Power Adapter` menus.

And make sure you click Report in case it's a bug in the operating system, which is possible since OSX 10.10 is fairly new.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for delayed reply, due to the holidays.

First of all I would recommend some basic maintenance based on number of errors your have in different sections, that might also need some repairs.

1 - Use Disk utility and repair permissions.

2 - Then use the cmd-r and repair the user ACL's (via terminal -password reset but without actual password reset).

3 - Then I would recommend to temporary disable trouble makers like GitHub for Mac app.

Now test again and if needed report here.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to have been solved. See: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6596475

> I also tried booting into Diagnostics and some other stuff.
>   Then I tried creating a new user, and found that the error was user specific.
>   So I logged back into my user and found all the files named
>     `Kernel_<datestamp>_<computername>.gpuRestart`
>   in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`. And I just moved away those files, and the error popup disappeared ...

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.